# How to switch transport protocols in Apache Thrift

Tags: thrift

The Apache Thrift [netstack](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/concepts) neatly explains that the transport protocol can be raw TCP, HTTP, etc. I however could not find a proper documentation which describes how I can switch between use of transport protocols underneath, maybe I am missing something here.

Also, a small follow up question, as I configure before building Thrift on my ubuntu system (`./configure` ), I see the following:

```
    C++ Library:
   Build TZlibTransport ...... : yes
   Build TNonblockingServer .. : yes
   Build TQTcpServer (Qt4) .... : no
   Build TQTcpServer (Qt5) .... : no
```

Should I be alarmed that the `TQTcpServer` was not configured to be built, given that I want to use a TCP transport protocol?

I am new to Thrift, excuse my lack of experience for framing the question better.

Comment: "*Should I be alarmed that the TQTcpServer was not configured to be built*" -- only if you plan to use Qt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thrift has the concept of endpoint transports, layered transports and protocols stacked onto each other to form a concrete implementation. The [tutorial](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/cpp) shows the basic principle (this is the C++ version):

```
  boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
  boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
  boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
  CalculatorClient client(protocol);
```

If you need to switch transports, in theory you simply remove the `TSocket` line and plug in another transport of your choice. In practice, there may be some more subtleties to it, but that's the basic idea. The [test suite code](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/test/cpp/src/TestClient.cpp#L250) can serve as an quite good example how to do this in practice:

```
  if (ssl) {
    factory = boost::shared_ptr<TSSLSocketFactory>(new TSSLSocketFactory());
    factory->ciphers("ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
    factory->loadTrustedCertificates(pemPath.c_str());
    factory->authenticate(true);
    socket = factory->createSocket(host, port);
  } else {
    if (domain_socket != "") {
      if (abstract_namespace) {
        std::string abstract_socket("\0", 1);
        abstract_socket += domain_socket;
        socket = boost::shared_ptr<TSocket>(new TSocket(abstract_socket));
      } else {
        socket = boost::shared_ptr<TSocket>(new TSocket(domain_socket));
      }
      port = 0;
    } else {
      socket = boost::shared_ptr<TSocket>(new TSocket(host, port));
    }
  }

  if (transport_type.compare("http") == 0) {
    boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> httpSocket(new THttpClient(socket, host, "/service"));
    transport = httpSocket;
  } else if (transport_type.compare("framed") == 0) {
    boost::shared_ptr<TFramedTransport> framedSocket(new TFramedTransport(socket));
    transport = framedSocket;
  } else {
    boost::shared_ptr<TBufferedTransport> bufferedSocket(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
    transport = bufferedSocket;
  }
```

This is again C++ and only the client side. There's also a [counterpart for the server end](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/test/cpp/src/TestServer.cpp) that works very similar.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!